# Corrupted file content dowloading with resteasy microprifile rest client

Tags: quarkus, resteasy

Downloading a file with this client method:

```kotlin
    @GET
    @Path("/download")
    @Produces(APPLICATION_PDF)
    fun getDocument(): ByteArray
```

I get bytes as `[37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 55, 10, 37, -17, -65, -67, ... more]`
The PDF file is corrupted.

Downloading the same file with a `curl`

```bash
curl --request GET      --url https://api.app/download      --header 'accept: application/pdf' -o doc.pdf
```

I get bytes as `[37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 55, 10, 37, -30, -29, -49, ... more]`
The PDF file is fine.

I don't see what I can do to fix this.

In the logs I do see the query flying with proper headers:

```
DEBUG [org.jbo.res.rea.cli.log.DefaultClientLogger] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) MDC[ps= rpm= capi=] Request: GET https://api.app/download Headers[Accept=application/pdf User-Agent=MyServiceAPI (- / -) X-CorrelationID=srv00014.out01], Empty body
DEBUG [org.jbo.res.rea.cli.log.DefaultClientLogger] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) MDC[ps= rpm= capi=] Response: GET https://api.app/download, Status[200 OK], Headers[Access-Control-Allow-Origin=* Allow=GET Cache-Control=no-cache, private Content-Disposition=attachment; filename=doc.pdf Content-Type=application/pdf <other meaningless headers>], Body:
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
    @GET
    @Path("/download")
    @Produces(APPLICATION_PDF)
    fun getDocument(): File
```

is working much better, but it creates the file in `/tmp` which is not great, but at least I stick to the REST client.

Comment: The file is likely created as it doesn't want to keep all the bytes in memory as that could cause issues. The file should likely get deleted.